# vector.insert() causes memory corruption

Tags: c++, vector, memory-corruption

I am not very experienced with C++, so I might be missing something obvious.
I am aware of the "invalidated iterator" issue with vector.insert, but I don't see how that could happen in this case.
There is also some OpenMP involved, but the insert itself is placed outside the parallel block.

```
void doWork(vector<Solution> &sol)
{
    vector<Solution> partial[40];

    #pragma omp parallel for ... shared(partial) ...
    for (...) {
        ...
        partial[tid].push_back(Solution(i,j));
        ...
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        sol.insert(sol.end(), partial[i].begin(), partial[i].end());
}
```

EDIT:
The error message is std bad alloc.
I am sure there aren't more than 40 threads. Apparently, this happens (on and off) even with 1 thread.
What's more interesting is that an alternative solution:

```
for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < partial[i].size(); j++)
        sol.push_back(partial[i][j]);
```

seems to work all the time, on a variable number of threads.

Comment: there is missing () after the end (in the line before the last one). Can this be related?

Comment: how do you know you have memory corruption? What error do you get? Sometimes memory errors surface in a location different from the root cause.

Comment: Frequently, memory corruption doesn't happen where it's noticed -- the corruption happens earlier, but you don't see a problem until you try to use the corrupted memory in a certain fashion. Are you sure there are no more than 40 threads? (you should use a vector of vectors, so that you can dynamically resize to the number of threads) Are you sure you don't have two threads doing `push_back` on the same vector?

Comment: Does `std::vector` have sufficient locking that `push_back` can be called from a `#pragma omp parallel` directive? AFAIK no, which might go a long way to explaining any subsequent errors.

Comment: @ildjarn except I think it might be wrong if `tid` is the thread ID here. I'm not sure either way, normally you'd use `omp_get_thread_num()` to get the thread ID though which I can't see any mention of. My money is on something else funky in the parallel block though.

Comment: @awoodland : True, unfortunately the code in question has too many `...` placeholders to give a _definite_ answer.

Comment: @awoodland tid is initialized and there are no 2 threads trying to push_back in the same vector. As I've stated, the alternative gathering method based on push_back instead of insert appears to be working consistently fine.

Comment: @MihaiOprea - *"appears to work consistently fine"* proves **nothing** about the correctness or otherwise of a C++ program.